# Need to remove class in WP (Chrome issue)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome

I am having an issue on Chrome in this site: http://itn.inbucc.com/wp/v1/

The top right menu button (Products) allow me to show a Side Menu, and return when i click outside the Area. Now, this code works in chrome outside WordPress (http://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/), but not inside (my WP theme). So i want to make a onclick function to remove the class, but is not working.

The original code is this:

```
(function() {

    var bodyEl = document.body,
        content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
        openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
        closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),
        isOpen = false;

    function init() {
        initEvents();
    }

    function initEvents() {
        openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        if( closebtn ) {
            closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        }

        // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
        content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( isOpen && target !== openbtn ) {
                toggleMenu();
            }
        } );
    }

    function toggleMenu() {
        if( isOpen ) {
            classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
        }
        else {
            classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
        }
        isOpen = !isOpen;
    }

    init();

})();
```

and I wanted to add this:

```
$('#quoteopacity').click (function(){

    $('body').removeClass('show-menu');

});
```

Comment: Is your jquery code executed when document is ready ? Are you sure to have a DOM element with `id='quoteopacity'` ?

Comment: Yeah. i have all that. The Body core is just as the Codrops example.

Comment: When I look at the console on your website (ctrl+shift+j on chrome), I see `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. So it appears that jquery isn't successfuly included. Also, you don't have a DOM element with this `id`, you do have DOM element with this `class` though.